# Google VR SDK for Samsung Gear VR?

Tags: oculus, google-vr, samsung-gear

Would Google VR SDK work on Samsung Gear VR (Oculus) or am I bound to Oculus SDK? Or are there any other alternatives (preferably open-source)

Answer (score 2):

Google's VR SDK will work fine on devices that you plug into GearVR with a normal cardboard headset. If you want to use the GearVR headset as a cardboard alternative, then it is also possible - you have to disable Oculus home and GearVR service.

This is said to work: [CB Enabler for Gear VR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youtopiavr.cbenabler) (did not check by myself)

Answer (score 0):

While you'll still need to have the Oculus SDK in your project, a library like [VRTK](https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK) can help you abstract away a lot of the pain of working with multiple headsets. It supports both Daydream and Oculus (as well as a host of others).